# File folder sql programming

Tags: sql

I'm trying to figure out the best way to make a file folder system in sql.
I'm making a website that will be using similar system as explorer in windows.

You open your c: drive and you see there some folders and files, and you open one folder and you see more files and folders there.

So what i'm asking, would i use one table for this and just point to the parent id number or what ?

I have this in my head.. You make a Primary folder, it gets the u_id=1. Then i make a file in that folder, it gets u_id=2 and p_id=1 so i know its there right? same with the folders.

This would all be in one table but i cant help thinking there is some major flaw in this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would tackle this in a few different ways:

Add a `Folders` table with these columns and whatever else you need:

```
FolderId [INT]
ParentFolderId [NULL INT]
Key [VARCHAR(MAX)]
```

What the Key holds is every ParentId of the current child combined like so:

```
19-144-444-
```

What this lets you do is easily find child folders without recursion.

Add a `Files` table with these columns:

```
FileId [INT]
FolderId [INT]
```

For the most part, files will have much more meta data associated with them so there's no reason to overuse one table

Comment: I'd especially follow this method with Key if your RDBMS doesn't have a good way to facilitate recursive queries (many don't).

Comment: so if i understand this right.. the key holds the id of everything that is under that current folder.. ?
Little lost :o

Comment: No, the Key holds all of its ancestors

Comment: so if this was T-SQL you could write `SELECT * FROM Folders WHERE Key LIKE '22-332-%'` which will get you all children of this folder all the way down the chain without recursion

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing is a tree hierarchy.
You are correct in using a recursive key to indicate parent-child relationships.

A good design example:

```
ID int (PK)

Parent int nullable (FK)

Foldername varchar(100)
```

Use files as per hunter's post